# How to configure Shibboleth SP running on NGINX web server on CentOS 7?

Tags: nginx, centos7, shibboleth

I have the Metadata of IDP and already installed Shibboleth on a server system running on CentOS 7. The steps I followed from this link -

- http://accc.uic.edu/answer/how-do-i-install-and-configure-shibboleth

which is very straight forward and good to follow. But it's for Apache web server.

The thing is, as per Shibboleth Website

- https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPConfigurationElements

I can't find an official support docs for NGINX webserver. I've checked many repositories on github but kind of hard to understand about the steps of configuration.

1. https://github.com/nginx-shib/nginx-http-shibboleth
2. https://github.com/ConsortiumGARR/idem-tutorials/blob/master/idem-community/HOWTO-Shibboleth/Service-Provider/Debian/HOW%20TO%20SETUP%20A%20SHIBBOLETH%20SP%20WITH%20NGINX.md